# How to copy DataTable row to Object in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

For example, I have an object of class:

```
class MyClass
{
public int a { get; set; }
public string b { get; set; }
public DateTime c { get; set; }
}
```

And I have a DataTable object with columns with same names as in a MyClass.
Is there a fast/simple way to copy each row of DataTable object to a MyClass object.

Like this (but in my case i have too much columns):

```
for (int x = 0; x < dataTableObj.Rows.Count; x++)
{
myClassObj[x].a = dataTableObj.Rows[x]["a"];
myClassObj[x].b = dataTableObj.Rows[x]["b"];
myClassObj[x].c = dataTableObj.Rows[x]["c"];
}
```

Thank U.

Comment: If the columns in your datatable are named the exact same as the properties in your class, you could use `Reflection`...

Comment: Why don't you use EF or Linq2SQL and map your class directly to the database table?

Comment: Why do you have already `dataTable.Rows.Count` objects in `myClassObj`? I would use a `List<MyClass>` and add a new instance in a `foreach`. Btw, reflection is always slower and more error-prone than creating instances manually.

Comment: "for () {}" with .Count optimizing by compiler and works faster (really I never using foreach)

Comment: Yes, i need supamegafast perfomance.

Comment: @HariSeldon The speed difference of those two is entirely negligible, if even existent.

Comment: Well, if you really need "supamegafast" performance, you should use SqlDataReader instead of SqlDataAdapter, and forget about reflection: do it manually.

Comment: @AllThePerformanceIssues you're doing a database call.  That will minimize the relative effect of pretty much everything else.  The network action will end up taking 99% of the time anyway, improving .01% of <1% of the runtime is...pointless (unless you've profiled the code to demonstrate it's a problem area).

Comment: Well, I'm looking for code like:
dataTableObj.Rows[x].ReflectToObject(myClassObj[x]);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For that exact purpose I am using this method below, datatable columns and type properties should have same names.

```
public static List<T> TableToList<T>(DataTable table)
{
  List<T> rez = new List<T>();
  foreach (DataRow rw in table.Rows)
  {
    T item = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
    foreach (DataColumn cl in table.Columns)
    {
      PropertyInfo pi = typeof(T).GetProperty(cl.ColumnName);

      if (pi != null && rw[cl] != DBNull.Value)
      {
        var propType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(pi.PropertyType) ?? pi.PropertyType;
        pi.SetValue(item, Convert.ChangeType(rw[cl], propType), new object[0]);
      }

    }
    rez.Add(item);
  }
  return rez;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Y're life saver. With legacy code that I am maintining I was able to convert rapidly DataTable to List of Objects. Now my question is about performance, all of us know that reflection is not as performant as That, any issues faced with this when dealing with huge data volumes ?

Comment: well, you can ditch reflection and make specialzed methods for each class that you use. But please profile that code before changes, only that way you can be sure what is slow.

Comment: I add here some tip for dealing with Nullable : before passing to Convert.ChangeType do the following and change pi.PropertyType with t :             Type t = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(pi.PropertyType)
                                    ?? pi.PropertyType;

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to modify the below code to match your needs.

```
var myBindings = System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance
        | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public 
        | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.SetProperty;

foreach (var row in table.AsEnumerable())
{
    MyClass newObject = new MyClass();
    foreach (var property in typeof(MyClass).GetProperties(myBindings))
    {
        if (table.Columns.Contains(property.Name))
        {
            //optionally verify that the type of the property matches what's in the datatable
            property.SetValue(newObject, row[property.Name]);
        }
    }
    //add newObject to result collection
}
```